# 302 status code using React Router v6 redirect from a loader function

Tags: redirect, react-router-dom

Inside the loader function I'm checking if the the user is authenticated. If not, the app should redirect to '/login'.

```js
export async function loader() {
 try {
    requireAuth();
    return await getVans();
  } catch (error) {
    throw redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting 302 status code. How can I fix this?

[image]

I tried to use hooks such as useNavigate and useHistory but they don't work inside the loader function.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

Don't throw the response as an error, return it.

```js
export async function loader() {
 try {
    requireAuth();
    return await getVans();
  } catch (error) {
    return redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. The thing is that I was using the latest version of react-router-dom as of now (v6.14), and once I reinstalled with a more stable version like 6.4 then it worked. I'm pretty sure you have the same problem you're having now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because of Mirage JS.

With an update made to v6.4.5 of React Router Dom, Mirage JS is causing some errors when using the `redirect` function from React Router. `tl;dr`: a library that Mirage JS is using under the hood (`pretender`) uses a polyfill for `fetch`, and that polyfill does not adhere to the `fetch` specifications, in that it does not return a response with a `body` property. In React Router 6.4.5, they included a new check to make sure that a response has a body property, which makes any `redirect` call in React Router fail.

You can work around this issue by modifying the response that comes back when calling `redirect`, like so:

Instead of

```
return redirect("new-url")
```

You can capture the response in a variable and add a body property manually:

```
const response = redirect("new-url)
response.body = true  // It's silly, but it works
return response
```